# DRBD 9 with existant LVM (RHEL 6.9) no resource defined

Tags: redhat, cluster, lvm, drbd

i'm trying to configure DRBD 9 on 2 RHEL 6.9 with LVM configured

when i try to do drbdadm create-md amss_drbd the result is
No resource defined

i've a .res file xxx_drbd.res with this configuration on each node

protocol C;
device /dev/drbd1;
disk /dev/mapper/vg-lv_oraData;
on xxx-prod-db1 {
address 10.20.101.81:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}
on xxx-prod-db2 {
address 10.20.101.82:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}
}

the /dev/mapper/diskname is an existand Volume i would like to replicate on both nodes.

Any idea?

thank you in advance.

S.

Answer (score 0):

for everyone... my fault..

the configuration file is under 
/usr/local/etc/drbd.conf

;)